# How to code a subscript i within a function?

Tags: r

I have the following function that I am trying to write in R:
[image: f(x)]

Currently, I have the following code, but I don't understand how to denote the subscript i?

```
f5 <- function(x) {((x^4 - 16*x^2 + 5*x)/2)}
```

Comment: You should have `f5 <- function(x) {sum(x^4 - 16*x^2 + 5*x)/2}`. If your `x` is a vector, then no need to deal with subscript `i` within the function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are (at least) two ways to do this, an explicit (`for`-loop) way and implicit (vectorized) way.

### for loop

```
function(x) {
   s <- 0
   for (i in seq_along(x)) {
      s <- s + (x[i]^4 - 16*x[i]^2 + 5*x[i])/2
   }
   s
}
```

(A previously posted answer suggested that you can use `sapply()`, but it's a little harder to understand than the explicit `for` loop ...)

### vectorized

Since R automatically performs standard arithmetic operations (`^`, `*`, `-`, `+`, `/`) in a *vectorized* way, you can compute this expression on all of the elements at once, then use the `sum()` function. The vectorized solution is faster and easier to read (once you get used to it).

```
function(x) {
   sum((x^4 - 16*x^2 + 5*x)/2)
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you everyone for the quick responses! I should have been more specific, I am needing a loop for the calculation. Ben, your explanation is very helpful!

Comment: @Scott217 I’m confused: why do you need the loop? Is your actual equation substantially different from the one you’ve posted? Explicit `for` loops are rarely needed or a good way to solve a problem in R.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, maybe a homework question?  ("Code the following computation by using a for loop ..." Apart from something super-obscure, that's the only context I can think of)

Comment: @KonradRudolph It is just an illustration of how to use a for loop to solve the problem, of  course this should be avoided in a clean code. This is my understanding.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I suppose a for loop is not necessary, but yes this is a homework question that I have been stumped on. The exact question is: (a) Implement the function $f(x)$ for any value of $n$ ($n$ represent the dimension in this problem).

Comment: @Scott217 I may be belabouring the point but nothing in that phrasing says that you need to use a loop.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, You are correct a loop is not necessary.